# Function parameter type for Mongoose schema, in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, mongoose

I am trying to work out what is the right parameter type, for a mongoose document passed as parameter to a function.

Starting with the definition:

```
import mongoose, { Schema, Document } from 'mongoose';

export interface IUser extends Document {
  email: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

const UserSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  firstName: { type: String, required: true },
  lastName: { type: String, required: true }
});

export default mongoose.model<IUser>('User', UserSchema);
```

Then we have a function that looks like:

```
function updateUser(user: IUser) { 
  user.firstName = 'something';
  user.lastName = 'somethingElse';
  user.save();
}
```

The issue here is that the Document type doe not have a `save()` function, so it fails. At the same time I can't specify `User`, since it throws the error "'User' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.ts(2749)".

The user parameter is an object of a `findOne()` operation.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
import { Model } from "mongoose";


function updateUser(user: Model<IUser>) { 
  cost newUser = new user({
   firstName:'something',
   lastName:'somethingElse',
})
  return newUser.save();
}
```

if you are working in a different file you will need to import also the IUser interface.

Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up solving this by adding the `@types/mongoose` module and then the function as presented in the question worked.

Comment: @types/mongoose has been deprecated as mongoose publishes its own types. Any idea how to solve this problem without this package? I'm currently having the same issue.